# How to prevent my ID from duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an edit button which I can click, this will fetch the desired JSON file and shows it back in my CMS side. However when I click on the edit function all works fine and good untill I add a new exercise. when I click on the green + button, instead of incrementing the ID (where it left, for example 2, so the ID of the third one should be 3) it starts with 0. and therefore I have double ID with ID 0 and so on. I have a delete button that should delete the exercise field based on its ID. So when I have 2 exercise fields with both ID 0 it will target the first one instead of targetting the targetted exercise field. 
It cannot recognize I already had exercise fields with certain IDs and therefore just starts all over with ID 0.

a picture for you to see:
[image]

See how they both have ID 0?

So what I am trying to achieve is the next thing: They should all keep their IDs, and whenever I append a new exercise field it should keep on incrementing instead of having the IDs duplicate.

How my delete button looks like:

```
function getRemoveBtnExercise(target, i){
  var RemoveExerciseBtn = $('<a/>', {
      'class': 'btn btn-danger'
   }).on('click', function(){  
   console.log($('.eblock').prop('id'))
        $('#' + target).remove();
   }).html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');

   return RemoveExerciseBtn;
}
```

how the eBlock looks like:

```
function getExerciseBlock(i, data){
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
    'id': i,
    'class': 'col-md-6 eBlock well'
  });

  data = data || {
    word: '',
    syllables: ['','','','']
  };

  console.log(data.syllables);

  $(eBlock).append(
    getRemoveBtnExercise(i),
    getAudioBtn(i),
    getWordInput(i, data.word),
    getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables)
    );

  return eBlock;
}
```

In case this is useful code, how the green add button for new exercise fields is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 0;
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success',
    'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
    $('#my_form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select();
    id++;
    exerciseAudioInput++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

  $('#my_form').append(addOpdracht);
  $('#my_form').append(getExerciseTitle());
});
```

Comment: What does the value of $('.well').length say?

Comment: Right now nothing, but that's an idea I had in mind. Right now I just use the ID of my function to target it. to be more specific: I use the ID of the function getExerciseBlock

Answer (score 0):

You could just generate a unique string, for example using `Math.random()` (which results something like this: `0.1459432599412`), and then encode it in base64 to make it legal html id.

```
function generateId() {
}
```

Of course it's not **guaranteed** to be unique, but it's fairly improbable.

PS: If you need further access to those ids, you can encapsulate it in a dedicated object that can generate new ids, and allow you to get old ones.

```
class Identifiers {
    construct() {
        this.ids = [];
    }
    getNext() {
        const id = this.getRandomId();
        this.ids.push(id);
        return id;
    }
    getRandomId() {
        return btoa(Math.random());
    }
    getId(id) {
        return this.ids.indexOf(id);
    }
}
```

and you could use it like so

```
const ids = new Identifiers();
const first = ids.getNext(); // MC41MjQyMTE5MTMyNDIyOTY0
const second = ids.getNext(); // MC41NzI4MTk3MjE2MjU3NjYy
// ...
ids.getId(first); // 0 (because it was first)
```

Comment: For the sake of my own brain: Isn't there a solution for the button NOT to start, but rather start at the last ID found. for example: if it finds 3 and I click on "add" for it to make the next exercise field 4 and so on?

Comment: @JJShaw could you create a jsfiddle for us to see? It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I could put it in a jsfiddle, but it won't replicate my problem since it requires a JSON file to fetch back. But I could provide a jsfiddle with the full code (most likely useless)

Comment: Can't you just paste tan example JSON file in the fiddle?

Comment: i don't think so (I can), but the problem occurs when you click on the edit button. My green add button cannot recognize there are already X exercise fields with X IDs. It thinks there are no exercise fields and it should start with 0.

Comment: Why not? Just create a variable `const myJson = '{field:value}'` and use it, instead of making an Ajax call. I need to see the code, and the application to help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

In the snapshot above, have you added all the three exercises using the javascript code, or the first 2 were pre-added, and you added the third one using the javascript?

Because in that case, it will start from `id = 0` only, you must start the `id` count one plus the number of exercises already available.

UPDATE:

Let's say you keep the exercises in the `div` tag with `class="exercise-box"`

And you have, 5 exercises when the page loads,

```
<div class="exercise-box">...</div>
<div class="exercise-box">...</div>
<div class="exercise-box">...</div>
<div class="exercise-box">...</div>
<div class="exercise-box">...</div>
```

Then you can add the following in your javascript code, if you are using jQuery,

```
var numItems = $('div.exercise-box').length;
```

And then initialise your `var id = numItems + 1;`
and keep the remaining code as it is.

Seeing your code, you can use `eBlock` in place of `exercise-box`, as you have included that class in the `div`.

Comment: you make an exercise as a teacher for you students, after 2 months you click on an edit button because the exercise has become old. You had the 5 exercise fields with words. When clicked on the edit button it will fetch the desired JSON file and put it back into the right exercise fields so you can change the data. However whenever you now were to click on the green add button because you want to give your students 5 more exercises it will start the ID with 0 again instead of recognizing you already had 5 exercise fields.

Comment: @JJShaw Correct. That is what I mentioned, you initialize `id` with `0` in your javascript code, while actually, you should initialize with `6` in the example you gave above. You will have to check the existing exercises listed on your webpage, and using that information initialize your `id` everytime page is loaded.
Getting my point? You should name the container `<div>` or whatever tag you use to hold the individual exercises, and in your javascript code, count the number of those named exercise tags, and initialize `id` with value, one plus the count of exercise already loaded on the page.

Comment: But my question now would be remain: How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Store it in the wrapper and increment it each time perhaps.

Original edit:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // get a reference to the form cache that to avoid multiple DOM hits
  var myform = $('#my_form');
  // this stores the value, I assume none existed before here...
  myform.data("myid",0);
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success',
    'id': 'addOpdracht'
  }).on('click', function() {
    // get last the stored value on the click event
    var id =  $('#my_form').data("myid");
    $('#my_form').append(getExerciseBlock());
    $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + id).focus().select();
    exerciseAudioInput++;
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>');

  myform.append(addOpdracht);
  myform.append(getExerciseTitle());
});

function getExerciseBlock(data){
  // get the last stored value and add 1 to it
  var myid = $('#my_form').data("myid") + 1;
  // store the new value back in there.
  $('#my_form').data("myid",myid )
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
    'id': myid,
    'class': 'col-md-6 eBlock well'
  });

  data = data || {
    word: '',
    syllables: ['','','','']
  };

  console.log(data.syllables);

  $(eBlock).append(
    getRemoveBtnExercise(myid),
    getAudioBtn(myid),
    getWordInput(myid, data.word),
    getWordPartInput(myid, data.syllables)
    );

  return eBlock;
}
```

I added this CRUD example to get you started, not perfect and not 100% what you have (I had no insight into some things) but functional in adding, removing, editing rows to a list with buttons)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create row on startup
  let newdata = {
    name: "name-ready",
    title: "Titlenew",
    audio: "Pete Sings the blues"
  };
  addNewRow(newdata);
});
$('#editor')
  .on('click', '.addnew', function(event) {
    let ed = $(event.delegateTarget);
    let newdata = getCurrentValues(ed);
    addNewRow(newdata);
  })
  .on('click', '.removeme', function(event) {
    alert('I would call some remove thing');
  })
  .on('click', '.saveme', function(event) {
    let ed = $(event.delegateTarget);
    ed.find('.showediting').addClass('disabled');
    let id = saveEditRow(ed);
    //  alert('I would save somewhere id:' + id);
  })
  .on('click', '.clearme', function(event) {
    let ed = $(event.delegateTarget);
    let storeFirst = true;
    clearValues(ed, storeFirst);
  })
  .on('click', '.cancelme', function(event) {
    let ed = $(event.delegateTarget);
    restoreValues(ed);
    let row = $('#exercises').find('.row.edit-active');
    row.removeClass('edit-active');
  });

$('#exercises')
  .on('displaydata', '.row.eBlock', function() {
    let data = $(this).data('rowdata');
    $(this).find('.title').html(data.title);
    $(this).find('.name').text(data.name);
    //TODO: $(this).find('.audio').text(data.audio);
  });

function saveEditRow(ed) {
  let data = getCurrentValues(ed);
  restoreValues(ed);
  // console.log(data);
  let row = $('#exercises').find('.row.eBlock.edit-active');
  data.rowid = row.data('rowid');
  row.removeClass('edit-active');
  row.data('rowdata', data);
  row.trigger('displaydata');
  return data.rowid;
}

function getCurrentValues(ed) {
  let currentdata = {
    name: ed.find('.editname').val(),
    title: ed.find('.edittitle').val(),
    audio: ed.find('.editaudio').val()
  };
  return currentdata;
}

function getRowValues(ed, row) {
  let currentdata = row.data('rowdata');
  return currentdata;
}

function storeValues(ed) {
  let en = ed.find('.editname');
  let et = ed.find('.edittitle');
  let ea = ed.find('.editaudio');
  en.data('lastvalue', en.val());
  et.data('lastvalue', et.val());
  ea.data('lastvalue', ea.val());
}

function setValues(ed, data) {
  let en = ed.find('.editname');
  let et = ed.find('.edittitle');
  let ea = ed.find('.editaudio');
  en.val(data.name);
  et.val(data.title);
  ea.val(data.audio);
}

function restoreValues(ed) {
  let en = ed.find('.editname');
  let et = ed.find('.edittitle');
  let ea = ed.find('.editaudio');
  en.val(en.data('lastvalue'));
  et.val(et.data('lastvalue'));
  ea.val(ea.data('lastvalue'));
}

function clearValues(ed, storeFirst = true) {
  if (storeFirst) {
    storeValues(ed);
  }
  let en = ed.find('.editname');
  let et = ed.find('.edittitle');
  let ea = ed.find('.editaudio');
  en.val('');
  et.val('');
  ea.val('');
}

function addNewRow(data) {
  let exercises = $('#exercises');
  let rowId = exercises.data("excersiseid") + 1;
  exercises.data("excersiseid", rowId);
  data.rowid = rowId;
  let igp = $("<div class='input-group-prepend' />");
  let iga = $("<div class='input-group-append' />");
  let addColumns = 5;
  let row = newRowGroup(rowId, addColumns);
  row.data("rowdata", data);
  row.find('.eItem').first()
    .removeClass('col').wrap(igp)
    .html(getEditBtnExercise(rowId, data));
  row.find('.eItem').eq(1)
    .html(getExerciseName(rowId, data.name));
  row.find('.eItem').eq(2)
    .html(getExerciseTitle(rowId, data.title));
  row.find('.eItem').eq(3)
    .removeClass('col').wrap(iga)
    .html(getAudioBtn(rowId, data.audio));
  row.find('.eItem').last()
    .removeClass('col').wrap(iga)
    .html(getRemoveBtnExercise(rowId));
  exercises.append(row);
}

function getExerciseTitle(rowId, title) {
  var titleEl = $('<span/>', {
    'class': 'title row-title'
  }).on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.row.eBlock')
      .data('rowid');
  }).text(title);
  return titleEl;
}

function getExerciseName(rowId, name) {
  var nameEl = $('<span/>', {
    'class': 'name row-name'
  }).on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.row.eBlock')
      .data('rowid');
  }).text(name);
  return nameEl;
}

function newRowGroup(rowid, addColumnsCount, addClasses = false) {
  let eBlock = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'row eBlock well input-group ',
    id: 'eblock-' + rowid
  }).data("rowgroupid", rowid);
  // create column we will clone and add to row
  let colcls = 'eItem ';
  if (addClasses) {
    colcls = colcls + 'col-md';
  }
  let props = {
    class: colcls,
    text: ""
  };
  let newcol = getCol(props);
  for (var c = 0; c < addColumnsCount; c++) {
    newcol.clone().appendTo(eBlock);
  }
  return eBlock;
}

function getCol(props) {
  let newcol = $('<div></div>', {
      class: 'col'
    })
    .addClass(props.class)
    .text(props.text);
  return newcol;
}
$('#addnew').on('click', function() {});

function getEditBtnExercise(rowId, data) {
  var edit = $('<button/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-success btn-sm editrow',
    'id': 'edit_' + rowId
  });
  edit.on('click', function() {
    let row = $(this).closest('.row.eBlock');
    row.addClass('edit-active');
    let id = $(this).data('rowid');
    let editor = $('#editor');
    storeValues(editor);
    editor.find('.showediting').removeClass('disabled');
    let data = row.data('rowdata');
    setValues(editor, data);
    // console.log(data);

  }).html('<i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i>');
  edit.data('rowid', rowId);
  return edit;
}

function getRemoveBtnExercise(myid) {
  var removeOpdracht = $('<button/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
    'id': 'removeOpdracht_' + myid
  }).on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-minus fa-2x"></i>');
  return removeOpdracht;
}

function getExerciseBlock(data) {
  var exercises = $('#exercises');
  var myid = exercises.data("excersiseid") + 1;
  $('#exercises').data("myid", myid);
  let eBlock = $('<div/>', {
    'id': "eblock-" + myid,
    'class': 'container eBlock well'
  });

  data = data || {
    word: '',
    syllables: ['', '', '', '']
  };
  eBlock.append(
    getRemoveBtnExercise(myid),
    getAudioBtn(myid),
    getWordInput(myid, data.word),
    getWordPartInput(myid, data.syllables)
  );

  return eBlock;
}

function getAudioBtn(myid, audioname) {
  var audio = $('<button/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary btn-sm audio row-audio',
    'id': 'audio_' + myid
  }).data("audioname", audioname).on('click', function() {
    let audioName = $(this).data("audioname")
    playAudio(audioName);
  }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-2x"></i>');
  return audio;
}

function playAudio(audio) {
  alert('Requested: ' + audio);
}
```

```css
#exercises {
  border: solid lime 1px;
}

#exercises .row {
  border: solid white 2px;
}

#exercises .row.edit-active {
  border: solid blue 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="editor">
  <div class="input-group md">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm showediting disabled" type="button"><span class="fa fa-tasks"></span></button>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm addnew" type="button"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></span></button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control editname" placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="changeme name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control edittitle" placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="New Title">
    <input type="text" class="form-control editaudio" placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="Walters Blues">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm clearme" type="button"><span class="fa fa-eraser"/></button>
      <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm cancelme" type="button"><span class="fa fa-ban"/></button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm saveme" type="button"><span class="fa fa-save"/></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="exercises" data-excersiseid="0">
</div>
<div>
```

Note for this function it might be best to change to use the newly create value: so it matches that newly created - note I am not 100% sure what the class `.exerciseGetWordInput_` thing really is about

```
.on('click', function() {
    $('#my_form').append(getExerciseBlock());
    $(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + $('#my_form').data("myid")).focus().select();
    exerciseAudioInput++;
  })
```

Comment: Can I keep on using "i" as ID however? or am I not possible to do so?

Comment: You can change `myid` to `i` yes, I changed it just to illustrate it is NOT being passed TO the function but obtained from the wrapper IN the function, making the function more independent from the caller.  Note there is NO global now, which is a good thing.  Also note I do not know what ` exerciseAudioInput++;` is but that might also be added to the wrapper - global variables are nearly always a bad idea

Comment: Ah, I see... I'm sorry for the newbie question here but: you use "myid", myid but how can you use an increment between quotes? Doesn't that make it a string?

Comment: That is the "key" to the data property of the wrapper - so that is a reference to that value.   See the data documentation https://api.jquery.com/data/  Note it can be anything that you want like "myexerciseid" or whatever, that is independent of the local variable `var myid`

Comment: I added a note at the bottom - not 100% sure as I noted just what that part is about there...it is normally very odd to increment a class.

Comment: I KNOW IT, but I need help with how to code it: I want to insert the next if statement into the function getExerciseBlock. `if (i.length equals the highest i) next i +1` something like this should be able to do so within the function right?

Comment: I will update to show an entire add/delete within a list of them example,  may take a short bit to get back to it...